# What is the IRREP of the $p_z$ orbital in a $C_s$ point group?

Tags: atomic-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

What is the representation on the $p_z$ orbital in a $C_s$ symmetry group?

The $C_s$ symmetric group has two irreducible no. of representations
$A^{'}$ --->  $s, x, y, xy$    and
$A^{''}$ ---> $z, xz, yz$

To which one of these representations does the $p_z$ orbital belong?

Comment: You can easily look this up in a character table for $C_s$. See this one for example  http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=102&option=4

Answer (score 1):

A p-orbital transforms like a single Cartesian coordinate and belongs to the same irreducible representation as the corresponding coordinate. I.e. if you want to determine to which irrep $p_z$ belongs, you have to look for the $z$-coordinate in a character table. In the $C_s$ group, that would be the $A''$ representation.

When you have irreducible representations of higher dimension, orbitals come as a set and you have to look for the corresponding set of coordinates. An example would be the 2-dimensional irreducible representation E of the D3 point group, where the set $(x,y)$ forms a basis for the irrep. The corresponding set of $p$-orbitals is then $(p_x,p_y)$.

It is similar for d-orbitals where each d-orbital is associated with the corresponding product of cartesian coordinates. I.e. the $d_{xy}$ orbital belongs to the irrep of the cartesina coordinate product $xy$.